# dotnet continues to work when docker stopped

Tags: .net, docker, nginx, .net-core

At first, I pulled my image from my Docker HUB

```
docker pull username/repo
```

Then ran docker image:

```
docker run -d -p 5050:80 username/repo
```

Then configured `nginx` to listen on port 80 and proxy pass to http://localhost://5050

Then checked that my .net core `webapi` worked well - it's worked

And after all of this when I stopped docker container, like this:

```
docker stop CONTAINER_ID
```

My container stopped, but I see that port 5050 listen by dotnet 
And my webapi continues to work

What's wrong? Why is dotnet working when not in a docker container?

Here my Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5050/tcp

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*5050
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT docker

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5050"]
```

Comment: If you stop and then the container restarts it might be your restart policy. Do a stop and then a `docker ps` to see how long it has been up for.

Comment: check if nginx is caching the response somehow...

Comment: @ShawnC. After the `docker stop` by `docker ps` I see an empty list, also when I kill dotnet process  in 30 seconds it again is on the `netstat` list and also listens on port 5050

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee sendfile set to on in nginx.conf